# Database connection closes after the first request

Tags: database, rest, go, http

I write APi on golang and i encountered an error. After one request server return error that sql database is closed. I want to transfer the database connection through the context.

main.go

```
func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    db, err := sqlx.Connect("pgx", os.Getenv("POSTGRESQL_URL"))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(5)
    db.SetConnMaxLifetime(5 * time.Minute)
    db.SetConnMaxIdleTime(5 * time.Minute)

    defer db.Close()

    configure_router.ConfigureRouter(app, db)

    if err = app.Listen(os.Getenv("PORT")); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

configure_router.go

```
func ConfigureRouter(app *fiber.App, db *sqlx.DB) {
    //Middlewares
    app.Use(logger.New(logger.Config{
        Format: "[${ip}]:${port} ${time} ${status} - ${method} ${path}\n",
    }))

    app.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        //AllowOrigins: "http://localhost:3000",
        AllowHeaders: "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
    }))

    app.Use("/api", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        ctx.Context().SetUserValue("dbConn", db)
        return ctx.Next()
    })

    //Authentication endpoints
    app.Post("api/register", register.Register)
    app.Post("api/auth/login", login.Login)
}
```

register.go

```
func Register(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
    conn := ctx.Context().UserValue("dbConn").(*sqlx.DB)

    var in In

    if err := ctx.BodyParser(&in); err != nil {
        return make_response.MakeInfoResponse(ctx, fiber.StatusUnprocessableEntity, 1, err.Error())
    }

    if in.Email == "" || in.Password == "" {
        return make_response.MakeInfoResponse(ctx, fiber.StatusBadRequest, 1, "Incorrect data input")
    }

    elementExist := false
    err := conn.Get(&elementExist, "select exists(select email from users where email = $1)", in.Email)

    // Here programm fall in second request
    if err != nil {
        return make_response.MakeInfoResponse(ctx,fiber.StatusInternalServerError, 1, err.Error())
    }


    if elementExist {
        return make_response.MakeInfoResponse(ctx, fiber.StatusBadRequest, 1, "User already registered!")
    }

    passwordHash, err := hash_passwords.HashPassword(in.Password)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = conn.Exec("insert into users (email, password_hash) values ($1, $2)", in.Email, passwordHash)

    if err != nil {
        return make_response.MakeInfoResponse(ctx, fiber.StatusInternalServerError, 1, err.Error())
    }

    return make_response.MakeInfoResponse(ctx, fiber.StatusOK, 0, "Registration was successful!")
}
```

If i send request in /api/register and user already registered in first request i get

Requst:

```
{
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "password": "123123123"
}
```

First response:

```
{
   "error_code": 0,
   "message": "User already registered!"
}
```

But if i will want send another one request i will get:

```
{
   "error_code": 1,
   "message": "sql: database is closed",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to transfer the database connection through the context.

*Don't*. Not only is it bad practice, but it is actually the `fasthttp.RequestCtx` itself that is closing your db after each request. Contexts should hold ONLY **request specific** values. A global db connection is hardly request-specific.

See the docs of [`SetUserValue`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.SetUserValue), specifically the last paragraph:

> All the values are removed from ctx after returning from the top RequestHandler. Additionally, Close method is called on each value implementing io.Closer before removing the value from ctx.

---

A quick fix would be to capture the db in a closure:

```golang
func Register(db *sqlx.DB) (fn func(*fiber.Ctx) error) {
    return func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // ...
        elementExist := false
        err := db.Get(&elementExist, "select exists(select email from users where email = $1)", in.Email)
        // ...
    }
}

// ...

// delete this or comment it out
// app.Use("/api", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
//    ctx.Context().SetUserValue("dbConn", db)
//    return ctx.Next()
// })

app.Post("api/register", register.Register(db))
```